# Display an array of string into a table with three columns in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of Strings like below :

```
nameArray = ["Str1","Str2","Str3","Str4",......];
```

I need to display this data into tabular format with three columns like below :

```
Col1       Col2       Col3
--------------------------
Str1       Str2       Str3

Str4       Str5       Str6

Str7       Str8       .....
```

Need help to write logic to display the above data in Angular, TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  input = ["Str1", "Str2", "Str3", "Str4", "Str5", "Str6", "Str7", "Str8", "Str9", "Str10"];
  output = [];

  constructor() {
    const size = 3;
    for (var i=0; i < this.input.length; i+=size) {
      this.output.push(this.input.slice(i, i+size));
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of output; let i=index; let last=last">
      <ng-container *ngIf="!last">
        <th>
          Col {{i + 1}}
        </th>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of output">
    <td *ngFor="let col of item">
      {{ col }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6gnqzp)

Answer (score 0):

`toTable` function will split nameArray required column chunks. it takes an optional parameter for no of columns, defaults to 3

```
  public nameArray = ["Str1","Str2","Str3","Str4",'st5', 'st6', 'st7', 'st8', 'st9'];
  public data = [];
  public columns = [];
  public toTable ( columns=3 ) {
    let i = 1;
    while ( i <= columns ) {
      this.columns.push ( `Col${i}`);
      i += 1;
    }
    for (let i=0,j=this.nameArray.length; i<j; i+=columns) {
        this.data.push ( this.nameArray.slice(i,i+columns));        // do whatever
    }
  }
```

Use this html template for rendering the info in a table format

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let node of data" >
    <td *ngFor="let point of node">{{point}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```